# GoLang Dependency Not found - google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc

Tags: go, dependencies

**Problem description**

I have a dependency which I need to update to the latest version (1.1.0 to 1.2.0), but when I do and I run `go mod tidy` - although initially the 1.2.0 version has been downloaded, it is immediately removed since it's not used directly from the module.

I am trying to identify why I am I using `google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc` in my code.

***I've tried the following:***

- `go mod graph | grep protoc-gen-go` -> no results
- It also seems that the module is related to an indirect dependency since the following command shows me that the main module does not directly use this module.

  ```
  go mod why -m google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
  # google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
  (main module does not need module google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc)
  ```

**More info:**

**go.sum** includes this line (generated automatically when i run `go mod tidy`):

`google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc v1.1.0/go.mod h1:6Kw0yEErY5E/yWrBtf03jp27GLLJujG4z/JK95pnjjw=`

Any ideas on how to identify and hence update the module will be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? That's a `main` package, so you cannot be using it in your code.

Comment: I have a tool that checks for vulnerabilities - so I am just trying to update vulnerable packages. In addition though, I am trying to get a better understanding of the situation I described.

Comment: You are either installing that binary and using it, or you are not. If you never install the package, then the vulnerability cannot affect you.

Comment: What if you've installed a package that has installed this vulnerability? That does not sound correct I am afraid @JimB

Comment: That does not make sense -- importing a Go package cannot install other binaries on your system. The only type of package that can be "installed" is a `main` package, so if you have not installed it, you are not using it.